# How to get data and display in html from firebase using angular/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display all  my posts with description title and price in my html using angular i am using **firebase**.
Here is my Code

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>
            Medical Tourism
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    {{title}}
    {{desc}}
    {{price}}
</ion-content>
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab label="Get Card" icon="information-circle" href="tabs/(get-card:get-card)">
        <ion-router-outlet stack name="get-card"></ion-router-outlet>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

When I **console.log()** I get all my posts whit all I need but when I get it on html there is just first post with description title and price.
But in Console i get it

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-medtour',
    templateUrl: './medtour.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./medtour.page.scss'],
})
export class MedtourPage implements OnInit {

    title: any;
    desc: any;
    price: any;

    constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {

        firebase.database().ref().child("medtour_posts/").on('value', (shapshot) => {
            shapshot.forEach((child) => {
                this.title = child.val().title;
                this.desc = child.val().description;
                this.price = child.val().price;

                console.log(this.title,this.desc,this.price);
            })
        })
    }

    ngOnInit() {}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well your console.log is inside the for each loop thats why it gets printed everytime. But you're assigning the value to the same variable each time. it gets overwritten. You'll need an array or multiple variables to display all

```
export class MedtourPage implements OnInit {

 childs: [];

    constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {

firebase.database().ref().child("medtour_posts/").on('value', (shapshot) => {
      shapshot.forEach((child) => {
       this.childs.push(
        {title:child.val().title),
         desc:child.val().description),
         price:child.val().price)};
     })
  })
}




<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
        Medical Tourism
    </ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding *ngFor="let child in childs">
    {{child.title}}
    {{child.desc}}
    {{child.price}}
</ion-content>
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab label="Get Card" icon="information-circle" href="tabs/(get-card:get-card)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="get-card"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-tab>
```

Comment: Thank you. Please can you tell me how can i achieve that?

Comment: i edited the my answer a bit. Its not a optimal solution but should work. I recommend you look up arrays, objects for javascript/typescript and ngFor for angular. It should get you on the right track

Comment: uhhh...its showing blank but in console it working correct.i think the problem is in html......

Comment: ok...now we did it..but here is one problem it  is displaying data incorrect. like title after title description after description)))))) not like tilte-description another title and description

Comment: Yes, thats because it iterates over array after array. You need one Array wich holds Object. In our case array childs wich gets loaded with an object in each loop.I edited the Answer again. Check out if it works for you

Comment: Hi my friend. Can you tell me how can i get the current title of clicked post?

Comment: `<ion-content  (click)="functionName(child.title)" padding *ngFor="let child in childs"> {{child.title}} {{child.desc}} {{child.price}} </ion-content>` kinda like that. You call your function with (click)="" and there it is child.title or {{child.title}} or something like that

Comment: Thank you very very much my friend i found the solution. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Can you PLEASE my friend show how the for loop in .ts file will work?